# How to get ObjectId (_id) of my document in MGO mongo db driver for golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm working with MGO (cause I didn't found anything better that it). 
I'have played with it and have got some result but I don't understand how to get the _id (internal Mongo  ObjectId) of document received?

For ex:

```
type FunnyNumber struct {
    Value int
    _id string
}

session, err := mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1:27017")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer session.Close()

// Optional. Switch the session to a monotonic behavior.
session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

c := session.DB("m101").C("funnynumbers")

funnynumber := FunnyNumber{}
err = c.Find(bson.M{}).One(&funnynumber)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println("Id one:", funnynumber._id)  // Nothing here? WHy? How to get it.
fmt.Println("Value one:", funnynumber.Value)  // 62. It's OK!
```

Could someone help me, please? Ot where might I read some info about it? I haven't found anything in the MGO doc

Schema of my document is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50778ce69331a280cf4bcf90"), "value" : 62 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: use mgo package to get Object ID

Comment: _id is not an exported field, meaning mgo cannot assign values to it.

Comment: Thanks guys for help.
Himanshu  - I just want to know how to do it =)
Peter - yes, but it must be possible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Change `_id` variable to uppercase(ID) to make it exportable.
2. Use `bson.ObjectID` as its type.
3. Add tag for struct `FunnyNumber` Id variable.
   field

Above three things should be done to get object Id value.

```
import "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson"

type FunnyNumber struct {
    Value int `json:"value"`
    Id bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`` // only uppercase variables can be exported
}
```

Take a look at package [BSON](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson) for more understanding on using bson tags when working with mongodb

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm getting this result 
  `ObjectIdHex("50778ce69331a280cf4bcfdd")`  but I have still a few question
  
1) To transform this ID into normal value should I use `**func ObjectIdHex** ?`

2) Could you explait a lil bit this stuff   - `Id bson.ObjectId` ? This is not a golang type. Is it directly type of MGO.BSON? What if I don't export the BSON package, is it be still available?
  
3) ` `bson:"_id,omitempty"` `  What is this?
   the same for  Value int `json:"value"`   ? What is this -> `json:"value"`

Thanks!

Comment: `json:"value"` is tag used when marshaling to json. Have a look at [String](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#ObjectId.String) of bson package to convert ObjectId to hex representation of string

Comment: Himanshu - Thank you so much friend! You are helped me a lot. Will check it.

Comment: Also we can use [Hex](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#ObjectId.Hex) function to get the hex representation of Object ID

Comment: @Velidan The Object id is created by mongo itself when inserting document until you create it. If you have created a unique id that is an integer. Mongo will use that as a unique id for document.

Comment: Thank you! I had deleted my question before you answered cause I didn't know if it not be annoying for you. Thanks. And I have figured out how to fetch an Int _id. Here ``` Id     type Student struct {
 Name   string
 Scores []ScoreItem
 Id     int `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
} ```. So we should degine which type we expect.

Comment: @Velidan It is not annoying. It feels good to help. Also bson tags are added to struct when working with mongo.